# CSS Only border on drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

If you hover over the "Technical" tab, you'll see a drop down menu appear, however, from the bottom right of the tab to the top right of the drop down  should be a border. How can I do this with only css? Or is JavaScript needed?

[dev site here](http://graham.diggsdev.com/)

Comment: I can't see any "drop down menu appear" :( (Chrome and FF)

Comment: Same here, no dropdown (Safari)

Comment: @SidharthMudgal Nor can I! (Chrome 22)

Comment: should be all good now! dno what happened...

Answer (score 1):

K I think I got it

```
#menu .ddsmoothmenu li#menu-item-36 li:first-child {
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 10
}

#menu .ddsmoothmenu li a {
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    color: #816363;
    font-size: 1.03em;
    z-index: 30;
}
```

It just looks a bit wierd while opening up, which you can fix by probably putting the border-top style to the submenu after the slide finishes.

Comment: ooo nice! except now when you hover over the sub-menu items, the border reappears for the bottom of the main nav item